# Injecting Google Analytics Tracking Snippet into Websites Behind Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, google-analytics, centos, reverse-proxy, javascript-injection

I've been wanting to use Google Analytics for a while now and I want to avoid inserting the tracking snippet manually into each webpage. Furthermore, it might not even be supported to do so with third party apps like Plex, Deluge, etc.

I host all of these services behind an Nginx Reverse Proxy. I understand it's possible to inject the Google Analytics tracking snippet into each `Location` block using the `ngx_http_sub_module` in combination with the `sub_filter` directive.

I have been trying to figure out how to do this for the past few hours now and have failed with several different configurations. Basically, I've gotten to the point now three separate times where my config will pass a linting test and I can successfully start the Nginx service, however despite Nginx functioning as expected, no metrics are ever delivered to Google Analytics.

Anyone have any ideas? Is it necessary to forward ports or anything to use Google Analytics? All outgoing requests are currently unfiltered, for what it's worth. Here are the configurations that I have tried so far:

**1) Global Site Tag:**

```
http {
    server  {
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name www.website.com;
        ssl  on;
        location  / {
            proxy_pass http://12.34.56.78:2000/;

            sub_filter   </head>
                    "<script>
                        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
                        <script async src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-##########-1'></script>
                        <script>
                          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                          gtag('js', new Date());

                      gtag('config', 'UA-##########-1');
                    </script>
                </script>";
            sub_filter_once on;
    }
}
```

**2) Analytics.js:**

```
http {
    server  {
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name www.website.com;
        ssl  on;
        location  / {
            proxy_pass http://12.34.56.78:2000/;

            sub_filter </head> '<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,"script","https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js","ga");ga("create","UA-##########","auto");ga("send","pageview");</script></head>';        

            sub_filter_once on;
    }
}
```

**3) Analytics.js without JS snippet embedded in config:**

```
http {
    server  {
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name www.website.com;
        ssl  on;
        location  / {
            proxy_pass http://12.34.56.78:2000/;

            sub_filter  </head>
            '<script language="javascript" src="/etc/nginx/analytics.js"></script></head>';
            sub_filter_once on;
    }
}
```

**analytics.js file referenced above:**

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-##########', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

**System Information:**

Operating System: CentOS 7.5
Nginx Version: 1.15.2
Included Modules: `http_ssl_module`, `stream`, `http_stub_status_module`, `http_sub_module`

**Sources I have consumed:**

*Sorry these aren't hyperlinks. StackOverflow said that my hyperlinks weren't "Properly Formatted as Code" as refused to let me make this post. Formatting them as code broke the hyperlink syntax so I had to do this....*

1) GitHub Gist Proof of Concept: https://gist.github.com/jirutka/5279057

2) Blog Post Proof of Concept: https://adarrohn.com/blog/nginx-google-analytics

3) Question on Ruby-Forum: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1985946

4) Google Analytics Docs on `gtag.js`: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/

5) Google Analytics Docs on `analytics.js`: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

6) Nginx Docs on `http_sub_module`: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it worked for me

```
sub_filter '</body>' '<script src="/tealeaf/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>\r\n</body>';
```

I.e. in one line.

Adding GA code to every website page is not what people do nowdays. I suggest start using GTM and insert GTM code snippet on every page (using same method through). Thay way, you will be able to customise your data collection without changing tracking code [much].

Things to check, you are not providing your website url in question here, but 
 - please load the page and make sure GA code snippet is included before the  tag

- please open the developers tools in your browser, switch to a network tab and cntrl+f5 (hard refresh) the page. Than look if file analytics.js was loaded from google server
- if yes, please look if a request to /collect google analytics endpoint is made.
  If this is true, you should be seeing the data in GA.

If none of the above, I would look if sub_flter is supported on the proxy_pass locations in nginx

Edited on 8 Aug 2018
[image: There is a problem with JS file]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. After checking the network tab in my browser it does appear that the javascript file is 404ing. This is because the file it's targeting isn't located on the public webserver, but rather somewhere else on the filesystem. Is it not possible to pass a static file to sub_filter? I wouldn't want to make this file publicly readable, after all, since it contains the private Tracking ID.

Comment: Your tracking ID is NOT private since your client-side library (javascript) needs access to it. There is no way you can hide it from a person who wants to extract it.

It does works for me with "local" file. Something wrong with a path? A way how nginx treat relative pathes?

What is your 404 requested url?

Comment: That makes sense. The problem was that I had the js file on my reverse proxy instead of the webserver. Ive since fixed that and now I have the reverse proxy inserting two different sub_filter lines depending on the subdomain you connect to. The first is your solution, and the second is the Global Site Tag one listed in 1) above. I can confirm that the analytics.js file is readable on the internet, additionally, both instances are injecting the script in the <head> section. However, The 'Network' part of the Dev Console shows no traffic to Google Analytics. And GA does not report any traffic :(

Comment: @TJZimmerman - can you share the website url, so I could have a look if it is being tracked?

Comment: Sure thing, here are the two examples mentioned above. Notice how the subdomain (and page source) is different for each. https://tjzimmerman.com & https://www.tjzimmerman.com | Lastly, here is the nginx config snippet that is injecting that information: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zimmertr/3f3fddba4c9d442f4c67fa61c6fae62e/raw/a2e0b694d26c6c1f0826a3c7618d55eeb1334278/gistfile1.txt

Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Comment: Was trying to attach an image, didn't work. But there is a problem with your GA code snippet. You copy/pasted snippet (which is HTML) into JS file (JavaScript) which browser is trying to interpret and obviously fails. Try removing < SCRIPT > tag, < / SCRIPT > and <!-- ... --> (HTML comments tags)